# Not able to load lightgbm under R 4.0

Tags: r, lightgbm

I'm not do install/run lightgbm under R 4.0. I was able to run models under R 3.6.3, which I still have in my computer. However, after installing R 4.0 I'm not able to even load `lightgbm` either on R 3.6.3 or R 4.0. Any help? Also, I'm using OS Catalina.

```
> library(lightgbm)
Loading required package: R6
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lightgbm’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lightgbm/libs/lib_lightgbm.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lightgbm/libs/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous installation steps for `{lightgbm}`, the R package for LightGBM, were somewhat fragile and could lead to issues like this when updating R versions.

Now that the package is [available on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lightgbm/index.html), I recommend uninstalling it and installing from CRAN. The version on CRAN has been tested on Catalina and should work for you.

```r
remove.packages("lightgbm")
install.packages("lightgbm", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")
```